# Can a Fighter use their Mark feature with a Grenade?

Tags: dnd-4e, mark, fighter

If a `Fighter` player character attacks with a grenade-like weapons, e.g. Acidic Fire [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=434)], can they still `Mark` the target(s)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.**

From PHB1, pg76:

> **Combat Challenge:** ... Every time you attack an enemy, whether the attack hits or misses, you can choose to mark that target. ...

Note that there are no restrictions on this. (Hybrid fighters are slightly different and require the use of a Fighter class power to mark a target.)

If the grenade-like weapon requires an attack roll (and all the ones I've seen do), then yes, the fighter can mark the target(s).

Comment: Note that if you are a hybrid fighter, this doesn't work as that specifies that the attack must be a fighter power

Comment: @ObliviousSage Thanks for the response. I assumed that was the case, but it came up in a recent game, and I thought it better to double-check